# How can I test this

Tags: c#, unit-testing, mocking

Lets say I have the following code, and I want to test that the `Data` class is correctly calling the `Update()` methods of the two item classes when `Dowork()` is called.

`

```
    public class Item1
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public void Update(string value) { Name = ...; }
    }

    public class Item2
    {
        public string Name { get; private set; }

        public void Update(string value) { Name = ...; }
    }


    public class Data
    {
        public Item1 Item1 { get; set; }
        public Item2 Item2 { get; set; }

        public void Dowork()
        {
            Item1.Update("Q");
            Item2.Update("W");
        }

    }
```

`

How can I achieve that if I can't modify the Item1 and Item2 classes (external code) to add interfaces that can be mocked?

One option is to check `Item.Name` and `Item2.Name` before and after `Dowork()` is called in a test, but aren't I then testing the implementations of Item1 and Item2? i.e if Item1 or Item2 change then my test breaks even though I am not testing their behaviour.

All I really care about is that Data is calling the Update methods when DoWork is called, not what the Item classes happen to do at that point.

Comment: You can wrap Item1 and Item2 in your own classes, and have those classes implement your own interface. Some mocking frameworks such as FakeItEasy might be able to provide fakes (or mocks) to Item classes, depending on some conditions. For more info, check out [What can be faked](https://fakeiteasy.readthedocs.io/en/stable/what-can-be-faked/)

Comment: Unfortunately wrapping them would mean making changes to lots of other code where they're used, which I was trying to avoid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to recommend you `NSubstitute` nuget package that you can use for mocking and check the method call easily.

```cs
[Fact]
public void Check_Method_Call()
{
  var item1= Substitute.For<Item1>();
  var item2= Substitute.For<Item2>();
  var data= new Data()
           {
             Item1=item1,
             Item2=item2
           };

  //call update methods
  data.Dowork();

  //check method calls
  item1.Received(1).Update("Q");//or you can use Arg.Any<string>()
  item2.Received(1).Update(Arg.Any<string>());

}
```

Comment: Ah! I've been using Moq, which doesn't let you do this unless the method Update() is marked as virtual (which I can't do as its external code). Interesting to see that it lets you do it in NSubstitute though. I guess they're doing things completely differently?

Comment: Also, even though it works (test locally) I'm a little confused as the documentation states it only works with virtual methods? https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/creating-a-substitute/

Comment: @BertTerb the document says, if you don't override a method, that method will actually execute (without mock it) so in your case you want to check if that method was called or not, for mocking a method you can follow this: https://nsubstitute.github.io/help/return-from-function/